# What protocol is NPS server using to send Secondary Auth to Azure MFA?

Tags: multi-factor, azure

We are using PAP to pass data between our on-prem VMware and on-prem NPS server. But our on-prem NPS Server passes data to Azure MFA in the cloud. **I want to ensure a stronger protocol than PAP is being used to pass data from NPS server to Azure MFA in the cloud, but I'm struggling to find an answer to what protocol is being used in this scenario.**

[image: NPS sending Secondary Auth to Azure MFA]

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the NPS connector a PowerShell script has to be run. This PowerShell script sets up an authentication method using X.509 certificates. PAP is not passed from the NPS server to Azure cloud.